# How to format the XML results from an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Morning,

I am trying to format some XML output from an SQL Query and I am struggling.  The SQL I currently have is something similar to this, I've changed the names of the tables and columns :

```
SELECT *
FROM ReportTable p with (nolock)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 s with (nolock) on s.UID = p.UID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 o with (nolock) on o.UID = p.UID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ct with (nolock) on ct.UID = p.UID
WHERE p.UID = 1194
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

And this is giving me the following output:

```
<p>
  <UID>1194</UID>
  <pCol1>Value</pCol1>
  <pCol2>Value</pCol2>
  <pCol3>Value</pCol4>
  <pCol4>Value</pCol4>
  <s>
     <UID>1194</UID>
     <sCol1>Value</sCol1>
     <sCol2>Value</sCol2>
     <sCol3>Value</sCol3>
     <o>
        <ct>
           <UID>1194</UID>
           <ctCol1>Value</ctCol1>
           <ctCol2>Value</ctCol2>
        </ct>
     </o>
  </s>
</p>
```

Which isn't what I am after, what I actually need is this:

```
<p>
    <UID>1194</UID>
    <pCol1>Value</pCol1>
    <pCol2>Value</pCol2>
    <pCol3>Value</pCol4>
    <pCol4>Value</pCol4>
    <s>
        <UID>1194</UID>
        <sCol1>Value</sCol1>
        <sCol2>Value</sCol2>
        <sCol3>Value</sCol3>
    </s>
    <o>
    </o>
    <ct>
        <UID>1194</UID>
        <ctCol1>Value</ctCol1>
        <ctCol2>1</ctCol2>
    </ct>
</p>
```

Is it just a case that I have to change my SQL so it use's sub queries, or have I missed something screamingly obvious with my SQL?

Ideally as well the solution will need to work for versions of SQL Server from 2000 up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XML PATH`

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    s.sCol1 as 's/sCol1', 
    o.oCol1 as 'o/oCol1'
FROM p 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN s on s.UID = p.UID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN o on o.UID = p.UID
FOR XML PATH
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522647.aspx